# How to send notifications in mobile apps to users with specific geolocation correctly?

Tags: android, ios, notifications, geolocation

There is mobile application, platform doesn't matter. Sometimes users create announcements about something, happened at specific geolocation (point). I want to send notifications (for example push, it also doesn't matter, it can be just some change in database) to users, located in some radius near that point.

I understand the easiest way to do it:

`I can store location of every user (who runs geolocator in background) and just send notification, when announcement is created on the server, selecting some people from database by circle of coordinates (and maybe time, when they were saved)`

It is really easy-to-realize method, buy it seems to me, that it is very bad idea to store location of all users and it has awful perfomance.

Am I wrong? Or is there better method to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you get or store the location locally? Then you can test when you check for notifications if the user is in the desired location?

Would be my solution. Check for notification from app => if there is one => check location => when is ok => show notification.

Comment: You mean sending notifications to ALL users and check location on client side. Unfortunatelly, I think, that it is worse, than store all locations :( I'm really using push-notifications, send notificaton to all users of application is bad idea..

Comment: Than there is no other way than storing your locations. Indeed get users from DB from server and send them a notification.

Comment: https://jeapie.com/blog/geo-location-targeting-push/ At the end of the article, seems interesting Geotargeting Fence